# Call functions while ending current function

Tags: python, function

So, Im coding a game, (just a simple text-based game, no fancy graphics or anything), but since im not good at coding professionally, I have everything done using functions, so that everything can call one another. this means that all functions and threads are always essentially 'loaded', I don't know the proper term.
essentially I want

```
def function():
     print("Hello")
     function()
```

to function as

```
def function():
     print("Hello")

while True:
     function()
```

but in my case, I can't do this, because I have many different functions being called from within each other in seemingly random patterns based on user input, and im worried at some point I'll hit a recursion wall, or stack overflow, or whatever it may be called.

AKA I can't use a loop because the order of the functions within the loop will vary from game to game

im pretty sure the only reason the stack overflow or whatever happens in the first scenario, is because the interpreter is yet to read any code after the function calls itself, as in if I had

```
def function():
     print("Hello")
     function()
     print("goodbye")
```

the interpreter has yet to come back and print goodbye, therefore it gets stuck in memory

Call a function while ending the current function, and never return to read anything after
similar to I guess a "Break"

call a function and end the current function at the same time to save memory

Comment: You might need to extend your example a bit to show why you think you can't use a loop.  A simple `while` loop won't overflow the stack the same way that the recursive call you're attempting to use will.

Comment: I don't think you know what AKA means.

Comment: All games like this, whether they have a graphical UI or a console UI, have the same basic construction.  Somewhere, there is a "main loop" where the application spends most of its time waiting for an event.  The event can be a keystroke, a mouse click, a timer, network traffic etc.  The main loop then "dispatches" those events to event handlers, which "do their thing", and then return to the main loop to wait for another event.  You don't have a function call itself like that.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  In particular, you should research how to write the central gaming engine for your type of game.  These engines are covered in many sites, many with template code you can use and adapt.  Using recursion in place of `while` is a common beginner error, and usually shows a fatal flaw in the project design.

Answer (score 0):

As for me better to create some functions, and then create `main` function where that all will run:

```
def function1():
    pass

def function2():
    pass

def main():
    print("function1")
    function1()
    print("function2")
    function2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```